# Proper way to set height of imageView

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

When im working in Swift on `NSLayoutConstraint` and I want set height of `imageView` what is proper way to do that:

**1) get view.frame.height CGFloat and use**

```
let viewHeight = view.frame.height
customNSLayoputConstraints.append(imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: viewHeight / 5))
```

**2) or use view.heightAnchor**

```
customNSLayoutConstraints.append(imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2))
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: @BrunoRocha thanks for answer, so how in your opinion should i get the height for imageView if i want imageView height always be 1/5 height of screen no matter of device position?

Comment: I misreaded the question! In this case, your second example should work just fine :) The first option will fail because while the view's frame will update, the constraint won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better option will be 2nd one. Its true what @BrunoRocha wrote in comment, constraints will update automatically when you get height from view.heightAnchor instead from frame.